# Problema al guardar en base de datos Django con SQlite3

Tags: django, sqlite

**PY**

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

from django.urls import path 
from .import views
urlpatterns = [        
    path('', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Person
from .form import PostForm


def post_new(request):
    form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'adm_coloegio/index.html', {'form': form})
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
from django import forms

from .models import  Person

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model =Person
        fields = ('first_name',  'last_name',)
```

**HTML**

```
{% block content %}
<form action="/" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Agregar</button>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Saludos, podrias agregar si te generar algun error ?

Comment: Por favor, agregue una descripción del problema. No sólo el código, si no una descripción breve para poder ayudarte y recomendarte.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import forms

from .models import  Person

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model =Person

    class Meta:
        fields = ['first_name',  'last_name']
```

Prueba con esos cambios. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando:

```
post = form.save(commit=False)
```

Haciendo que obtengas una instancia de Model, y los datos queden guardados en memoria y no en disco, por esa razón es que no encuentras los valores que ingresas por formulario en la base de datos. Esto se utiliza normalmente para obtener la instancia y agregarle más valores para posteriormente guardar en base de datos, por lo tanto la solución a tu problema seria simplemente quitar el "***commit=False***"

```
form.save()
```

Puedes encontrar esto en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

Saludos.